# Exec format error

Tags: linux, exec

I know this gets thrown around a lot, but it just didn't make sense to me. So, I compiled C code using the installed gcc compiler but it just would execute. Many other posts said that it was probably due to execution of a file on the wrong architecture, but I dont think thats the problem here. What's wrong here?

```bsh
$ uname -a
Linux stickyfingers 4.10.0-19-generic #21-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 6 17:04:57 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 
GNU/Linux

$ file exploit
exploit: ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped

$ ./exploit
-bash: ./exploit: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

Comment: Get rid of the `-c` option to `cc` or `gcc` when "compiling" your exploit.

Comment: Is it a system you're trying to hack into? `4.10.0-19-generic #21-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 6 17:04:57 UTC 2017` what an old kernel you have there.

Comment: How did you compile the executable?

Comment: Read `man readelf`, and use `readelf` to inspect the `exploit` file. Also read `man strace` and `strace ./exploit`. Also read `man ld.so`, which is where the `exec format error` comes from. Read `man ldd` and `ldd ./exploit`. Run `file` on the libraries listed.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to [user414777's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/414777/user414777) comment, I removed the -c flag and it's working.

Comment: Your question does not show a command that uses the `-c` option...